# how to edit a List<string> which is defined in a script in Inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i know that if you define a public property like `public string name`,then you can edit it in the unity3d Inspector

here is what i want, i defined a `public List<string> Names` property in a script

```
public class CloudBtree : MonoBehaviour{

    public List<string> Names;
    //...

}
```

but turn out to be that i can only edit its size property.the picture below shows what i mean:
[image]

how can i add or remove the string using the Inspector? anyway to do this?

Comment: you should be able to enter the size and then element0,element1... and so on will show after you enter the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the size of the list in the inspector
2. You should then see fields for entering values for each element (in your case, strings)

Comment: i've tried this before, but when the size textfiled lost focus, the size property just change back to 0 again.

Comment: thanks a lot, it seems that i have to press enter key not click on the white space then the size property can be changed properly.